Excel conditional formating not changing all cells in range
I have a conditional format that checks for text values in two cells and changes the background color on a range of cells:
=AND(C5 = "Manager", C8 = "Expert")

It should be applied to cells $E$4:$E$8 but only $E$4 changes. I saw a solution for checking values that required ABS to be placed before the formula but since I am doing a string check and not a number check this shouldn't apply.
Here's the Manage Rules screen to show it is being applied to the range:

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I can get it to work?

I think you need to add $ to lock the columns: =AND($C5 = "Manager", $C8 = "Expert")

You can read up on absolute vs relative references in Excel here

Thanks but that didn't fix it.

Lock the rows, not the columns, since the formula is being dragged along multiple rows. it should be C$5 and C$8

Answer: the formula should be =AND(C$5="manager",C$8="expert").
Description: See picture 1 below for the answer. When entering a conditional formula that is applied over multiple rows and looks at a static row reference, that reference must be locked to the row (e.g. C$5), where the $ precedes the row number. The same applies to columns, like if you were to apply this formula to $E$4:$W$7; you would need to lock the column reference (e.g. $C$5), where the $ now precedes the column letter.
What you should enter

What you are seeing (probably)

